# Why does alert(<%=myStringVariable%>); not work?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JavaScript function which does not give the result I want.

Here is the code (it is a part of a JavaScript function):

```
<%
    String myStringVariable = "no";
%>

alert("yes");                  // This alert gets shown.
alert(<%=myStringVariable%>);  // But this alert doesn't get shown.
```

I do not understand why the second alert does not work. Can someone identify the reason?

Comment: viewing the rendered page source probably would have answered the question for you.

Comment: @epascarello: You are right. What I expected was `alert("no")`. But, what the page source shows is `alert(no)`. I wonder why a String is not returned. Anyway, thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like as in Java, in JavaScript should strings be quoted.

```
alert("<%=myStringVariable%>");
```

You need to realize that this code doesn't run in sync. It's Java/JSP which runs first, generates a bunch of HTML/CSS/JS and sends it to the browser. Then it's HTML/CSS/JS turn to run. If you do a rightclick, *View Source* in browser, you'll see that Java/JSP has already done its job and there should be no single line of it.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) - Contains a chapter about JavaScript

Comment: As you have suggested, viewing the source is a good way to learn and identify errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
alert("<%=myStringVariable%>");
```